# passing arguments in oracle command using vb.net

Tags: oracle, vb.net-2010, par

am writing code in vb.net .am using select statement in oracle command . when i pass arguments values through variable am getting error.

```
my code
------
chk1 = TextBox1.Text
d1 = Date.Parse(chk1)


--------
--------
try
   cn.Open()

        cmd = New OracleCommand("select PHONE from  reports.renewal_contact_t where run_date=to_date('+ d1 +','mm/dd/yyyy') and  EXP_DATE =to_date('07/21/2012','mm/dd/yyyy')", cn)

 ------------
 ada.Fill(ds, "reports.renewal_contact_t ")
end try


eror(in ada.fill statement)
 -----
ORA-01858: a non-numeric character was found where a numeric was expected
```

Comment: And what would that error be, please provide the message/stack trace. Also, from your code it does not seem that you are passing a parameter for d1.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You haven't managed to put your date into your SQL query.  You're getting an error because Oracle cannot convert the string `+ d1 +` into a date of the form `mm/dd/yyyy`.  I get exactly the same error in SQL*Plus:

```
SQL> select to_date('+ d1 +', 'mm/dd/yyyy') from dual;
select to_date('+ d1 +', 'mm/dd/yyyy') from dual
               *
ERROR at line 1:
ORA-01858: a non-numeric character was found where a numeric was expected
```

There is a way to concatenate the date into the SQL string to get a query that would appear to work, but I'm not going to show you that.  I don't want you to get into the habit of doing this as this puts your code at risk of [SQL injection](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection) (obligatory [XKCD comic link](http://xkcd.com/327)).

Instead, I recommend that you set the date in your SQL query using a bind parameter.  The example code below uses a bind parameter named `p_run_date` to pass the date `d1` into the query, and writes the names of the phones returned by the query to `Console.WriteLine`.

I wrote code to do this in C#, tested it to verify that it did what I expected it to, and then attempted to convert it to VB.NET.  I haven't tested this VB.NET code, so there may well be one or two (hopefully minor) errors with the conversion:

```vb
    Using OracleCommand cmd As New OracleCommand("select PHONE from reports.renewal_contact_t where run_date=:p_run_date and EXP_DATE =to_date('07/21/2012','mm/dd/yyyy')", cn)
        cmd.Parameters.Add(New OracleParameter() { Direction = ParameterDirection.Input, ParameterName = "p_run_date", OracleDbType = OracleDbType.Date, Value = d1 })
        Using OracleDataReader reader As cmd.ExecuteReader()
            While reader.Read()
                Console.WriteLine(reader.GetString(0))
            End While
        End Using
    End Using
```

Answer (score -1):

In `vb` you might try:

```
cmd = New OracleCommand(
    "select PHONE from  reports.renewal_contact_t where run_date=to_date('" & d1 & "','mm/dd/yyyy') and  EXP_DATE =to_date('07/21/2012','mm/dd/yyyy')", cn)
```

This will concatenate your `d1` string to your expression